# differences scipy interpolate vs mpl griddata

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, interpolation

I'm almost tearing my hair out from this, and really hope someone can help me out here.

I need to convert a script from python 2 to python 3, its a simple script which takes in coordinate points `x`, `y`, and the values for those points `z`.

`z` is interpolated across a grid, and then plotted. Interpolation in the python 2 script is currently being done with `from matplotlib.mlab import griddata`

However, mlab griddata does not exist in python 3. So I see we're supposed to use `scipy.interpolate` as a replacement.

Problem is, it's giving me **really weird results.**

### **Nearest Neighbour Comparison**

Mpl griddata With `interp='nn'` gives me:

[image]

scipy interpolate using `method='nearest'` gives me

[image]

**This is the most important as this is the result i need, but the results are so different!**

I tried other parameters to see if this persists

### **Linear Comparison**

mpl griddata with `interp='linear'` gives me

[image]

scipy interpolate with `method='linear'` gives me

[image]

Linear shows the same results, but i dont care about linear.

### **Cubic Comparison**

mpl griddata doesn't have cubic, but the results are super weird with scipy interpolate.
[image]

**Data**

```
import numpy as np
# points
x = np.array([31132.71118116, 10763.66383076, 29340.62119857,  4025.2544491 ,
       19158.87683925, 36584.96725821, 17335.28090098, 27279.80878719,
        5893.32833709, 36392.22873482, 22350.16973122, 40235.86525991,
       19844.57893466, 11245.50791534, 17103.62528354, 29944.77964486,
       34021.92540595, 44485.36307614,  8797.36817447, 24733.44616607,
       30628.62812172, 27227.91858716, 26221.60497488, 27987.74985745,
       14366.37775758, 32035.24328142, 29779.84095199, 42821.14608703,
       42229.95963477, 22592.94483609, 26362.45107434, 22161.13844494,
       21562.53974235, 40784.42626907, 14195.87932099, 25628.56490406,
       19212.62065784, 28354.69294259, 34299.91259166, 28276.85653059,
       13291.49360218, 64014.88912569,     0.        , 64014.88912569,
           0.        ])
    
y = np.array([1.61640041e+04, 1.18226221e+04, 1.66496799e+04, 1.60268291e+04,
       1.47533260e+04, 1.72743862e+04, 2.58461610e+04, 1.11997818e+04,
       1.94747705e+04, 2.81559903e+04, 2.85786579e+04, 2.16418047e+04,
       2.58684064e+04, 2.17474690e+04, 3.21398453e+04, 2.13563269e+04,
       2.12339790e+04, 2.42537633e+04, 1.89242092e+04, 2.45410984e+04,
       1.90984612e+04, 2.45058762e+04, 1.76859142e+04, 2.13655953e+04,
       2.62595562e+04, 1.44826845e+04, 2.55328718e+04, 2.97076285e+04,
       1.81975446e+04, 3.27182416e+04, 1.88407910e+04, 1.58599943e+04,
       2.02514897e+04, 2.42723003e+04, 1.76265941e+04, 1.60045845e+04,
       2.03274941e+04, 1.67609034e+04, 1.74986867e+04, 1.78898244e+04,
       3.21546756e+04, 9.55042196e-08, 9.55042196e-08, 4.04414440e+04,
       4.04414440e+04])
    
z = np.array([0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0.6, 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. ,
       0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. ,
       0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. ,
       0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. ])
    
min_grid_val_x = 0
max_grid_val_x = 64014.88912569069

min_grid_val_y = 9.550421964377165e-08
max_grid_val_y = 40441.443993242734
    
# set up a square grid with the same extents as our measured data
numcols, numrows = 1000, 1000
xi = np.linspace(min_grid_val_x, max_grid_val_x, numcols)
yi = np.linspace(min_grid_val_y, max_grid_val_y, numrows)
xi, yi = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)
```

**Other Code**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mc
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
from matplotlib.colors import Normalize
import math

MODE == 'mpl'
if MODE == 'mpl':
    from matplotlib.mlab import griddata
    zi = griddata(x, y, z, xi, yi, interp='nn')
else:
    from scipy.interpolate import griddata
    points = np.array([[x[i],y[i]] for i in range(len(x))])
    zi = griddata(points, z, (xi, yi), method='cubic',fill_value=0)
    
min_val = math.floor(z.min())
max_val = math.ceil(z.max())
resolutions = [0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 3, 5, 10, 
               15, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80]
    
max_of_Z = z.max()
if (max_of_Z==0):
    levels = np.arange(min, min + (0.1 * 12), 0.1)
else:
    hit = False
    for res in resolutions:
        condition = res*12
        if condition > z.max():
            print("Using {}".format(res))
            levels = np.arange(min_val, max_val + condition, res)
            hit = True
            break
    if not hit:
        res = 90
        print("Using {}".format(res))
        condition = res*12
        levels = np.arange(min_val, max_val + condition, res)
    
norm = mc.BoundaryNorm(levels, len(levels)-1)

cmapV=ListedColormap([[0.73,0.90,0.97],
[0.66,0.87,0.97],
[0.57,0.82,0.95],
[0.49,0.76,0.91],
[0.40,0.69,0.87],
[0.32,0.62,0.83],
[0.26,0.53,0.77],
[0.20,0.44,0.71],
[0.14,0.34,0.64],
[0.13,0.29,0.56],
[0.12,0.23,0.47],
[0.11,0.17,0.38]])

# define map extent
lllat=1.1497
urlat=1.5133
lllon=103.5822
urlon=104.1579
# set up plot
plt.clf()
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(13, 6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, facecolor='w', frame_on=False)

# Set up Basemap instance
m = Basemap(
    projection = 'merc',
    llcrnrlon = lllon, llcrnrlat = lllat, urcrnrlon = urlon, urcrnrlat = urlat,
    resolution='h')

# contour plot
con = m.contourf(xi, yi, zi, zorder=1, alpha=None, cmap=cmapV, levels=levels, norm=norm)
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [this discussion](https://github.com/stoqs/stoqs/issues/734) on the [STOQS](https://github.com/stoqs)'s issues Github page, the closest approximation to the old Matplotlib's `griddata` default algorithm, i.e., *Natural Neighbor*, is obtained  using `scipy.interpolate.griddata` with `method='cubic'` and `rescale=True`.

That said, if the data you posted is representative of your real problem, none of your plots is insightful, because you shouldn't extrapolate from a single data point `(x=5893.32833709, y=19474.7705, z=0.6)` while all the other data  points have a *z* ordinate identically equal to zero.

Comment: hey, thanks for the response! I saw that post before, and it doesn't work for me either. trying `griddata(points, z, (xi, yi), method='cubic',fill_value=0, rescale=True)` gives me almost exactly the same plot as the last plot in the question. I would be ok with this plot if it only gave the region in the top left (i.e. ok with most of the points being 0). Yes this is real data, and will be a common scenario. The expected result for this case is ideally the first plot (NN)

Comment: @Wboy ① If you mentioned in your Q that you had looked at that issue, I'd possibly not lost my time answering ② when your data has a structure, the interpolated results are sensible, algorithm notwithstanding; on the contrary…

Comment: Apologies for wasting your time. I was looking for a way to replicate mpl's old griddata natural neighbours interpolation in python 3.